# Die Verwendung von ”welche” und ”einige”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Betrachten wir die folgenden Sätze, die hoffentlich korrekt sind.

> Nachbar Gregor: Wir haben ein Fest und bräuchten ein paar extra Stühle. Ich glaube, du hast welche.
>   Bettina: Ja, ich habe einige. Ich leihe sie dir gerne aus.

Ich habe gelernt, dass man „welche“ verwendet, wenn das Pronomen in Fragesätzen alleine ohne Substantiv steht. In Gregors Frage ist der Satz aber als Behauptung umformuliert und grammatisch also nicht als Frage zu betrachten. Wäre hier „einige“ möglich, besser oder eine gleichwertige Alternativ? Wie ist es mit der Antwort von Bettina? Könnte sie gleich gut „Ich habe welche“ gesagt haben?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*welche* bezeichnet grundsätzlich eine **unbestimmte** Menge, daher auch die Anwendung in Fragesätzen. Gregor hat nicht die geringste Ahnung, wieviele Stühle Bettina hat.

*einige* bezeichnet ähnlich ebenfalls eine **unbestimmte** Menge, allerdings ist das *Maß an Unbestimmtheit geringer*. Es ist definitiv mehr als ein Stuhl - Deshalb wird es auch von Bettina in der Antwort verwendet - Sie hat zumindestens eine ungefähre Vorstellung, wieviele Stühle sie hat.

Die beiden Wörter sind austauschbar, allerdings nicht mit 100% gleichem Informationsgehalt - Bettina könnte in ihrer Antwort auch "welche" verwenden, weil die genaue Anzahl ja nicht wichtig bzw. ihr im Augenblick sowieso nicht genau bekannt ist.

> Ja, ich habe einige

Ist allerdings eine u.U. "gefährlichere" Antwort, denn "einige" kann auch in eher sarkastischer Form verwendet werden, um "ziemlich viele" auszudrücken, wie in

> Das wird einigen Ärger geben
>
> Das wird ja wieder einiges kosten
>
> wir haben noch einige Sachen zu erledigen, bevor wir in den Urlaub fahren

D.h. Bettina könnte mit ihrer Antwort auch durchaus meinen, dass sie irgendwo eine ganze Lagerhalle voller Stühle hat. Diese mögliche Doppeldeutigkeit gibt es bei der Antwort mit "welche" nicht.

Comment: Danke. Wenn Gregor eine direkte Frage gestellt hätte,wie "Hast du welche?", hat er dann auch "Hast du einige?" sagen können?

Comment: @Beta. Hmm. Zur Not ja, es wäre nicht unbedingt falsch, würde sich aber komisch anhören. In einen Fragesatz gehört an sich schon *welche*. Würde er die Frage nicht direkt als Frage formulieren, sondern als Behauptung, könnte er "Du hast doch einige?" sagen. Vgl. Englisch "Do you have any?" vs. "Do you have some?" fällt mir dazu noch ein.

Comment: ... oder _einige_ durch _ein paar_ ersetzen: "Hast du ein paar?" ("Do you have a couple [of them]?") Das klingt für mich gleichwertig mit "welche".

Comment: Stimme zu: "Hast du ein paar Stühle" wäre ein eher gängiger Gesprächsbeitrag und gleichwertig mit *welche*.

Comment: Ich möchte hinzufügen, dass bei "Ich habe einige" mitschwingt, dass es eine vergleichsweise hohe Anzahl ist. Das Gegenteil wären "einige wenige". Weiterhin finde ich nicht, dass in "Das wird einigen Ärger geben", etc., Sarkasmus mitschwingt. Es sagt einfach aus, dass es eine unbestimmte, aber durchaus signifikante Menge Ärger geben wird.

Comment: @tofro, hast du in der Tat eine sarkastische Form gemeint? Weil es für mich eher ironisch als sarkastisch klingt...

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort "welche" gibt keine Informationen über die Menge - bis auf die Tatsache, dass es mindestens 2 sind.
"Einige" bedeutet, dass es mehrere sind.
"Einige" finde ich hier unhöflicher als "welche". Ich finde "welche" bei beiden Sätzen die passendere Variante.

Comment: Interessant, dass die eine Variant als unhöflich emfangen wird. Ganz neu für mich! Zeigt auf die viele, viele unbewußte Fallen, die es in Fremdsprachen gibt

Comment: Versteh mich nicht falsch - es ist nicht unhöflich, sondern ein wenig unhöflichER! "Einige" klingt für mich ein wenig fordernd, während "welche" neutral ist.

Comment: So wie etwa "Hast du einige überhaupt?" Das wäre für mich nachvollziehbar

Comment: Möglicherweise bin ich ja sprachlich ein gefühlloser Klotz, aber einen Höflichkeitsunterschied zwischen *einige* und *welche* kann ich leider nicht erkennen. *einige* drückt höchstens aus, dass der Fragende weiß oder stark vermutet, dass der andere mindestens einen Stuhl hat.

Comment: Mag sein, dass das subjektiv ist.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, das Pronomen ›einige‹ bezeichnet zwar in dem Sinne eine unbestimmte Menge, als da nicht ›fünfzig‹ steht, bezeichnet aber zum Beispiel höhere Quantität als das Pronomen ›manche‹:

Er spielt Golf?

– Ja, ich hab gehört, manche machen das.

vs

– Ja, das machen einige heutzutage!

---

›Welche‹ ist durch und durch ein Pronomen, also ein Funktionswort. Es steht dort nur als Platzhalter ohne irgendeinen Informationsgehalt. Das ist austauschbar:

Ich bräuchte Stühle. Hast du Stühle?

Ich bräuchte Stühle. Hast du welche?

›Welche‹ steht hier grundsätzlich, damit man sich nicht wiederholt. Es referiert auf die Stühle. ›Einige‹ würde hingegen eine größere Menge andeuten.

Hast du einige? Das ist ungültig, so spricht niemand. Deshalb kommt es auch befremdlich rüber.

Allerdings hat die Antwortgeberin die Wahl zwischen den beiden Pronomen:

– Ja, ich habe welche.

vs

– Ja, ich habe sogar einige!